# How can I convert ASCII 323534 into decimal 254

Tags: python, hex, ascii, converters

I have ascii data 323534, which is 254 in decimal.

How do I write this in python, so I have as input 323534 and as output an int with 254

thanks in advance. 
This did not work

```
DistanceP1 = chr(32)
DistanceP2 = chr(35)
DistanceP3 = chr(34)
DistanceAll = [DistanceP1,DistanceP2,DistanceP3]
distance = int(''.join(DistanceAll))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number `323534` is actually a hex representation of `254`.

[image]

You can instead do:

```py
print(bytearray.fromhex("323534").decode())
```

**Output**

```
254
```

Comment: Thank you. Super. Works

Comment: No problem, my pleasure!